# Excel: Formula to sort data set

Tags: excel, sorting

I have an excel sheet with some data, it looks like this:
[image]

I basically want to create a formula that will create the table in another part of the spreadsheet but showing only showing the index values that are above, but still sorted by date.  The same way it would be if you were to filter to only show rows where the index is >0.5 but still in order of ascending dates.

I have no clue how to even begin this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  What's wrong with simply `=B2` in the first cell and filling down?

Comment: You can use dates as numbers, so you can do something like `=If(A1>A2,[do something],"")` where A1 and A2 are formatted dates. "Greater Than" when comparing dates means "A1 is later than A2".

Comment: I would look into macros.  Doing this with formulas is kind of the wrong approach.

Comment: @n8 why are formulas the wrong approach?

Comment: Because formulas a far more complicated in this case.  What crams is asking for is a 4-step macro: 1) filter, 2) copy to new location, 3) sort, 4) unfilter.  This scenario is a strong example of when macros are better due to simplification.  There are a lot of ways to skin the cat, and I'm sure your approach works.  But the level of difficulty is very high as well as the performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses 5 functions:

- [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)
- [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
- [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)
- [ROW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d)
- [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Based on the above formulas this should work for you with excel 2010 and above.

I did make one adjustment to your source data and that is I gave it a header of Date.  If this is a problem we can hard code the columns to look in.

The IFERROR function is used as a catch all to display "" instead of error messages when you copy the formula beyond the number of results.  Its really just a formatting thing in this case.

The INDEX Function is our workhorse in the solution.  The format of the INDEX function is:

```
INDEX(range/array/table to search in, row to look in, column to look in)
```

In your case I assumed the source data started in A2 and went to D11 and row 1 was a header row.  This resulted in the formula being developed looking so far as:

```
IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$11,row number, column number),"")
```

Lets look at that column number first as its a little easier.  I am assuming we are building the new table with header starting in J1.  So in J2 I need to determine which column from the source table we need to be looking in.  So I use the MATCH function:

```
MATCH(What I am look for, In this 1D range, for a match type of 1,0 or -1)
```

So in the example case it becomes:

```
MATCH(J$1,$A$1:$D$1,0)
```

Note the locks $ being used.  J has no lock so as we copy right J will change, but the $1 will not.

We can now substitute that back into the equation we are developing to get:

```
IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$11,row number,MATCH(J$1,$A$1:$D$1,0)),"")
```

Now we just need to find the row number to look in.  We are going to use a special function called AGGREGATE.  What makes it special is that A) it has many function within it and B) at least two of those functions will perform ARRAY formula calculations without making the formula an array.  We are going to use the array part to develop a list of row numbers that match our criteria.  You example only has 1 criteria and that is the index must be greater than 5.  In terms of building the list from an array it would look something like this:

```
ROW($A$2:$D$11)*($B$2:$B$11>$H$3)
```

H3 is the cell I stored the criteria number in.  it has locks on it so it will not change as the formula is copied.  Same goes for the ranges we are working with.  That will generate a list of 0s and row numbers.  The AGGREGATE function has a second argument that we can use to ignore errors.  Therefore if we can make all those 0s errors, they will be ignored and not part of our final results.  We can do this by dividing by the logical test which produces either 1 for ture and 0 for false.  That would change the above formula to:

```
ROW($A$2:$D$11)/($B$2:$B$11>$H$3)
```

Since the example list is sorted in Ascending order and we want to preserve that order, we will tell aggregate to keep our row number sorted in ascending order as well, and therefore will need to use the SMALL sub-function of aggregate.  As such  the AGGREGATE function will look like:

```
AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$D$11)/($B$2:$B$11>$H$3),SOME K VALUE)
```

Almost there, just need to figure out what SOME K VALUE is.  This is really just an integer counter that we need to start at 1 and increase by one each row its copied down.  So we use the row function.

Option A)

```
ROW(A1)
```

OPTION B)

```
ROW(A2)-1
```

I elected to use option B in case cell A1 ever got moved somewhere which would really screw us over.  Since A2 is far less likely to be moved I used it.  the -1 is to subtract the number of header rows above A2. Now the AGGREGATE function looks like:

```
AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$D$11)/($B$2:$B$11>$H$3),ROW(A2)-1)
```

And what that will do as we copy down is supply us with a list of row numbers.  To make it relative to the index range we are looking in we will need to subtract 1 from the result to get the right index number.

```
AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$D$11)/($B$2:$B$11>$H$3),ROW(A2)-1)-1
```

Now we know what column to look in what row to look in and what table we are looking in, so our final function should be:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$D$11)/($B$2:$B$11>$H$3),ROW(A2)-1)-1,MATCH(J$1,$A$1:$D$1,0)),"")
```

---

Proof of concept

[image: Proof of concept]

Comment: Very nice. Noticed that in the screenshot the MATCH has a zero in the third argument but it's not there in the text above. I guess you could dispense with the Match in fact, just use =IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$D$11)/($B$2:$B$11>$H$3),ROW(A2)-1)-1),"") and pull across?

Comment: Did I leave out a zero?  dang it with all the cutting and pasting

Comment: @TomSharpe I had to think about what I was thinking about when I put that match in there.  I think I put it in in case they wanted to change up the order of the columns.  I guess technically it forces the header to be the same between the tables.

Comment: Yes it does make it more flexible and having to put the headers in doesn't seem to be much of a drawback.

Answer (score 0):

A VBA solution might look something like this. As you can see the first way is pretty old-school: others may be able to suggest a shorter way of doing it, but as mentioned in the comments it is pretty straightforward.

```
Sub CopyFilter()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fromRange, toRange As Range
Dim LastRow, LastCol, fromRow, toRow As Long
Dim i, j As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set fromRange = Range("A1")
Set toRange = Range("G1")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

toRange.CurrentRegion.ClearContents

' Copy Header
For j = 1 To LastCol
    toRange.Cells(1, j) = fromRange.Cells(1, j)
Next j

'Copy data
toRow = 1
For i = 2 To LastRow
If fromRange.Cells(i, 2) > 0.5 Then
    toRow = toRow + 1
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        toRange.Cells(toRow, j) = fromRange(i, j)
    Next j
End If

Next I
End Sub
```

I have to admit this more modern approach is a lot shorter and it also copies the formats (for the date) not just the values:-

```
Sub QuickFilter
With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
'Select
 .CurrentRegion.Select
' Filter in place
 .AutoFilter _
 field:=2, _
 Criteria1:=">" & ActiveSheet.Range("H3").Value
' Copy
 Selection.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("J1")
'Clear filters
 .AutoFilter
'Clear selection
 .Select
End With
End Sub
```

[image]
Credits to @n8

Answer (score 0):

But going back to the formula version of this, if the dates are increasing as they seem to be, it would be enough to use this to get the first row with index > .5 in (say) G2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$11,MATCH(TRUE,($B$2:$B$11>0.5),0)),"")
```

and this to get the next rows starting in G3:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$11,MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$11>0.5)*($A$2:$A$11>$G2),0)),"")
```

where both of these need to be entered as array formulae using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>